# Low disk space on filesystem root despite GParted showing 8GB free

Tags: filesystem, gparted, disk-usage

I keep getting the error message "low disk space on filesystem root, 200MB remaining.." message, but when I check disk usage it shows me 8GB free?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The error message is most likely referring to the `/boot` partition. The screenshot shows 255MB remaining from 477MB.

This is the home of the kernel and associated boot files. You should check that you don't have any unnecessary files here.

You may have old Kernel images left over in this directory. There is some documentation here relating to removing old kernels - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RemoveOldKernels

WARNING - Be very careful though with your boot configuration :-O

Hope that helps. Regards, Andi

Comment: The only kernel version related files I see directly under /boot/ are my current kernel version files and one previous version's files.

`dpkg -l | tail -n +6 | grep -E 'linux-image-[0-9]+'` shows lots of images though. I purged a few with `sudo update-initramfs -d -k 4.15.0-24-generic` and `sudo dpkg --purge linux-image-4.15.0-24-generic` but I don't see any space being freed up.

Comment: What files do you have on this partition?
It may be that everything is normal.... it just happens to be half full.